# cron job failing to find wmctrl

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have added a cron job to execute a python script that is dependent on wmctrl. The job would fail to execute properly and I have traced this to the fact that the cron job seems to be unable to use/find wmctrl.

I have one cron task added to my tab as follows:

```
* * * * * /home/tim/wmctrl -h > /home/tim/log.txt
```

but the result log.txt file is empty. This command works fine from the command line.

My cron env is as follows:

```
HOME=/home/tim
LOGNAME=tim
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/home/tim
```

and `wmctrl` is found in `/usr/bin/`

I have tried other plain python scrips and applications which all seem to be working fine.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suspect it's not that `cron` can't find `wmctrl`, but rather that `wmctrl` doesn't have access to your `DISPLAY` and other variables that would enable it to talk to the appropriate other processes it needs to to accomplish what you're asking it to do. `cron` jobs run in a rather limited user environment.

Comment: Try adding the interpreter of the script before `/home/tim/wmctrl`: something like `/bin/sh /home/tim/wmctrl`

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try this:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && /home/tim/wmctrl -h > /home/tim/log.txt
```

Comment: ... and hope that `DISPLAY=:0` is always going to be correct, which is a vain hope but probably works well enough if occasional glitches are tolerable, for example on your personal workstation.

Comment: A bit of an explanation may be in order here.  Cron jobs run as a direct child of the `cron` daemon and have no way to know if you have an X session and, if so, which one(s) are yours.  If you are not logged in, for example, or if you have multiple X sessions, this will not do what you want.

Comment: The `export` is kind of superfluous; just say `DISPLAY=:0 /home/tim/wmctrl -h >/home/tim/log.txt`.  Do you really intend to overwrite this file once per minute?

Comment: @tripleee  use `DISPLAY=:0` here just to say that wmctrl needs some Display to dependent on AND this will tell crontab to locate a Display.It works for me. If u need to tell something like how many Xsessions or so,u can do it in a bash shell file.